# Continual "Google Play Services has stopped"

Tags: google-play-services

On my Samsung phone (not sure which model), every few seconds I get the message "Google Play Services has stopped" with options to "Close app" or "Send feedback".

Regardless of choice, the message appears a few seconds later.

"Force Stop" and "Disable" are both disabled for Google Play Services. Uninstalling Google Play Services produces an error that uninstallation failed. And Google Play Store doesn't work.

How do I fix (or at least disable) the thoroughly broken and persistent Google Play Services?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you cant disable it 
You should go first Setting-Secure-administator apps 
You need to disable (find my phone)
Now you can disable google play service